# UnsatisfiableError glibc and cudatoolkit

Tags: conda

```
conda install  -c anaconda -c conda-forge -c nvidia cudatoolkit=11 tensorflow-gpu=2
```

I want to install cudatoolkit=11 and tensorflow-gpu=2, but conda gave me the following error message

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - cudatoolkit=11 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

If I run

```
conda install  -c anaconda -c conda-forge -c nvidia cudatoolkit=11
```

conda can successfully install cudatoolkit=11.

Since glibc is a system feature, why installing cudatoolkit by itself is ok?

Why isn't glic 2.31 in range >=2.17,<3.0.a0?

Comment: Conda Forge is likely the __glibc culprit. Can you try it without **conda-forge** and **nvidia** channels? E.g., `conda install --override-channels -c defaults cudatoolkit=11 tensorflow-gpu=2` Also, is that the only reported conflict?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I try to install a particular package and I get:

`Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Your installed version is: 2.31`

Comment: Any update on this? It's driving me nuts trying to install Comet ML version 3.18 in Docker and exactly this error happens.

Answer (score 7):

I am providing answer as I could not find outright reason and solution.
If you are installing from conda-forge channel in conda base env this problem is very likely to occur due to c-runtime difference between conda and conda-forge.
To solve this , create virtual-env make conda-forge channel as first and stick to it(Strict) for installing packages, I don't see any harm in sticking to conda-forge , and  have found many experienced people suggesting same (stick to conda-forge channel).

Answer (score 3):

Updating anaconda to the newest version solved my problem.

Try `conda update conda`?

Comment: which version do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Install fvcore and iopath with `conda install -c fvcore -c iopath -c conda-forge fvcore iopath`. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Let the environment solver choose the correct versions for cuda and tensorflow.

assuming you are setting up a new conda environment:

```
conda create -n <NAME> cudatoolkit tensorflow-gpu <packages> -c <channels>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in during docker build but not in the deployed container;

So I resolved it by doing conda install inside a bash script fed into docker cmd & not in the dockerfile