# conda install: Package zlib conflicts for zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

Tags: perl, conda

I am trying to install a given version of [perl-bioperl](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/perl-bioperl) with conda:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge perl

$ which perl
/home/hakon/miniconda3/bin/perl

$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

$ conda install -c bioconda perl-bioperl=1.7.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package zlib conflicts for:
perl-bioperl=1.7.8 -> perl-bio-samtools -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
python=3.9 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Your installed version is: 2.31

$ conda list | grep zlib
zlib                      1.2.11               h7f8727e_4  

$ conda list | grep libgcc-ng
libgcc-ng    9.3.0               h5101ec6_17
```

This is confusing to me. For example this message:

```
Package zlib conflicts for:
perl-bioperl=1.7.8 -> perl-bio-samtools -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
python=3.9 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
```

why is this a conflict when my current version of zlib is:

```
$ conda list | grep zlib
zlib                      1.2.11               h7f8727e_4
```

And what could I do to resolve this conflict (if it is a conflict)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Bioconda packages are generated with [very specific channel priorities](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels), namely `conda-forge > bioconda > defaults` and if one doesn't follow this, correct solving and dynamic library references cannot be guaranteed. So, a proper *ad hoc* installation command would be

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults perl-bioperl=1.7.8
```

#### Encouraged Workflow

However, I would strongly encourage bioinformaticians (and other practitioners that value reproducible workflows) to not use *ad hoc* commands. Instead, adopt the practice of only working from YAML files to define software environments:

**bioperl_1_7_8.yaml**

```yaml
name: bioperl_1_7_8
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - perl
  - bioperl=1.7.8
```

Use this with `conda env create -f bioperl_1_7_8.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create a new environment with `conda-forge` as default channel (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70816820/2173773) answer) instead of installing into the base environment:

```
$ conda create --name perl
$ conda activate perl
$ conda config --add channels conda-forge
$ conda config --set channel_priority strict
$ conda install perl
$ conda install -c bioconda perl-bioperl=1.7.8
```